# C-Input/Output From File-Insertion Sort

Tags: c

How can I do this programming?
Can you give many hint or advice me?

- c: Read the file and get the words to be alphabetic sorted (I did reading,but I didn't sorting)

Comment: This question is much too broad for StackOverflow. You need to attempt it yourself first (show your actual code) and then ask specific questions explaining what you have tried and what specific problems you have.

Comment: For c) and d), you need some way to store the words from the file, such as a matrix with enough columns to store the longest word, or an array of pointers to the words in a buffer.  You'll need to keep an original version of the words, then for d), make a copy of the words or pointers, get the time, do the sort, get the time again ..., doing this 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is worded poorly; is `c` supposed to direct you to read the words into an unsorted list?  That would make sense to me.

Anyway, design your `insertionsort` function to match the prototype of the standard library's `qsort`.  This way you can reuse your code and move the logic for comparing two words out of your sort function.  Determining whether a word "comes before" another word is trivial.

For calculating the running time of your algorithm, take a look at the `clock` function.  This does not return the running time of your program but be a better indicator of how much CPU time your sorting algorithm took.  A good way to minimize the running time of your program is to refrain from making system calls and heap allocations in your loops, if possible.  Note that insertion sort has a very bad worst-case time complexity but is very good for almost-sorted data.  Selecting the right sorting algorithm for your data set can make a big difference.